# what is the equivalent of word boundary meta-character in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I'm learning regex right now and get confused with `\b` or word boundary is defined.

I know that `\d` is equal to `[0-9]` and `\D` is equal to `[^0-9]`, 
`\w` is equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and `\W` is equal to `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`.

I've tried so many different combinations to make the equivalent for `\b` but have not succeeded.

My question is, can we make the equivalent of `\b`? Please provide an easy explanation.

Comment: `\b` is valid in Java just make sure to use `\\b`

Comment: Why do you need an equivalent for word boundary? Just use `\\b`.

Comment: i'm not asking about how to use word boundary, i know that in java you must use escape char to write `\b`, but what i'm asking is what is its equivalent? i'm just curious.

Comment: If it were easy to reproduce `\b` using some other construct, `\b` wouldn't be available in the first place.

Comment: Actually, you're wrong. Neither of your substitutions is correct. `\d` doesn't equal to `[0-9]`, as it may or may not (implementation-dependent) take Unicode digits into account; `\w` allows `_` too, so `\W` disallows `_` as well etc.

Comment: further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options:

**Option 1: using both positive and negative lookarounds**

```
(?:(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w))
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/25).

**Option 2: using only positive lookarounds**

```
(?:(?<=\W|^)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?=\W|$))
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/26).

It is not enough to test that the following char is a `\W` (for instance), as another answer suggests with `(?=\W)`, because `\W` must match a character, but `\b` works at the beginning or end of strings, where there is no character to be matched. To fix it, the regex in Option 2 introduces an alternation with the beginning and end of string assertions `^` and `$`

Answer (score 1):

Untested equivalent for \b:

```
(?<=\\w)(?=\\W)|(?<=\\W)(?=\\w)
```

These are zero-width positive look-behind and look-ahead assertions. This is what goes on on a word boundary.